# how to print unicode number series in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, unicode

I am just trying to print the Unicode number ranging from 1 to 100 in python. I have searched a lot in StackOverflow but no question answers my queries.

So basically I want to print Bengali numbers from ১ to ১০০. The corresponding English number is 1 to 100.

What I have tried is to get the Unicode number of ১ which is '\u09E7'. Then I have tried to increase this number by 1 as depicted in the following code:

```
x = '\u09E7'
print(x+1)
```

But the above code says to me the following output.

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

So what I want is to get a number series as following:

১, ২, ৩, ৪, ৫, ৬, ৭, ৮, ৯, ১০, ১১, ১২, ১৩, ............, ১০০

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str1
I wish if there is any solution to this. Thank you.

Comment: Computers do math in base 2 numbers represented as bits in a register. That's it. They don't have a concept of language. You always do the math operations as native (base 2) integers. Then, you can convert that to whatever representation you want when you display it to a person. So what you want to do is write an integer to Bengali output formatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. Convert the `character` to an `integer`. Do the addition and the convert it to `character` again. If the number is bigger than 10 you have to convert both digits to characters that's why we are using modulo `%`.

```
if num < 10:
   x = ord('\u09E6')
   print(chr(x+num))
elif num < 100:
   mod = num % 10
   num = int((num -mod) / 10)
   x = ord('\u09E6')
   print(''.join([chr(x+num), chr(x+mod)]))
else:
   x = ord('\u09E6')
   print(''.join([chr(x+1), '\u09E6', '\u09E6']))
```

You can try running it here
https://repl.it/repls/GloomyBewitchedMultitasking

EDIT:
Providing also javascript code as asked in comments.

```
function getAsciiNum(num){
    zero = "০".charCodeAt(0)
    if (num < 10){
        return(String.fromCharCode(zero+num))
    }
    else if (num < 100) {
      mod = num % 10
      num = Math.floor((num -mod) / 10)
      return(String.fromCharCode(zero+num) + String.fromCharCode(zero+mod))
    }
    else {
      return(String.fromCharCode(zero+1) + "০০")
    }
}

console.log(getAsciiNum(88))
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a translation table.  The function `str.maketrans()` takes a string of characters and a string of replacements and builds a translation dictionary of Unicode ordinals to Unicode ordinals.  Then, convert a counter variable to a string and use the `translate()` function on the result to convert the string:

```
#coding:utf8
xlat = str.maketrans('0123456789','০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯')
for i in range(1,101):
    print(f'{i:3d} {str(i).translate(xlat)}',end=' ')
```

Output:

> 1 ১   2 ২   3 ৩   4 ৪   5 ৫   6 ৬   7 ৭   8 ৮   9 ৯  10 ১০  11 ১১  12 ১২  13 ১৩  14 ১৪  15 ১৫  16 ১৬  17 ১৭  18 ১৮  19 ১৯  20 ২০  21 ২১  22 ২২  23 ২৩  24 ২৪  25 ২৫  26 ২৬  27 ২৭  28 ২৮  29 ২৯  30 ৩০  31 ৩১  32 ৩২  33 ৩৩  34 ৩৪  35 ৩৫  36 ৩৬  37 ৩৭  38 ৩৮  39 ৩৯  40 ৪০  41 ৪১  42 ৪২  43 ৪৩  44 ৪৪  45 ৪৫  46 ৪৬  47 ৪৭  48 ৪৮  49 ৪৯  50 ৫০  51 ৫১  52 ৫২  53 ৫৩  54 ৫৪  55 ৫৫  56 ৫৬  57 ৫৭  58 ৫৮  59 ৫৯  60 ৬০  61 ৬১  62 ৬২  63 ৬৩  64 ৬৪  65 ৬৫  66 ৬৬  67 ৬৭  68 ৬৮  69 ৬৯  70 ৭০  71 ৭১  72 ৭২  73 ৭৩  74 ৭৪  75 ৭৫  76 ৭৬  77 ৭৭  78 ৭৮  79 ৭৯  80 ৮০  81 ৮১  82 ৮২  83 ৮৩  84 ৮৪  85 ৮৫  86 ৮৬  87 ৮৭  88 ৮৮  89 ৮৯  90 ৯০  91 ৯১  92 ৯২  93 ৯৩  94 ৯৪  95 ৯৫  96 ৯৬  97 ৯৭  98 ৯৮  99 ৯৯ 100 ১০০